# how to use remember me functionality with own unique device id's

Tags: php, security, authentication

In this age we have different machines, devices and phones, but sometimes we would like to be remembered by our own name.

I have a website where one person should be able to check "remember me" on the device he is currently working on, and having this working on all of your devices in the house.

Currently I was using a remember me function which creates a hashed key, saving it in the cookie, and in the database.
However - when logging in with the same user, but on an other device, the hashed key in the database is overwritten so the remember me function on the first device is down.

I was thinking to ceate a session table to hold the different sessions, (although it might hold different sessions for one user as well)

So Question:

**How can I set/generate a unique session key for a device with php.**

a browser fingerprint won't do as I use same browsers on different devices.

anyone ideas?

ofcourse I need a secure solution, preventing copying the cookie to another device or changing cookie information  (from your user to admin) is important.

Comment: I'm not sure I get it... Do you want that anyone who uses a computer in your LAN gets logged as you automatically?

Comment: no not in my Lan - just anyone who uses the website should be able to check - remember me.
the thing is, you have a laptop, an ipad, and a work computer which you use on this very same website, and all should be able to be remembered just by using the cookie.
However, if I don't save a hashed key into the database, but just use a cookie I would easily be able to edit my cookie, and change the name to anything else because there's no verification on there.
Also I would not recommend to save a password into the cookie as well...

Comment: @Double0Seven - Username or Hash - What is the difference? They are both a string of bytes to identify one. But two usernames could possibly have the same hash and thus be frustrating for the person trying to use your system (or they could possibly long in and get the other persons privileges!).

Answer (score 0):

For a start having a hash key instead of a username does not **add** any extra security.

Just use a cookie with the username in it. The password is there for security.

Comment: ofcourse it will add security as I mentioned in my other comment.
Otherwise you could change the username to anything else into the cookie e.g. change pete to admin - and you're the admin of the site!?
When you add a key which you save in your cookie and also in your database you can check when you come back if the username = key in the db and let him in.

Comment: @DoubleOSeven - It does not. The password is the security bit. That bit you do not store in the cookie. The username (or hash) just identifies the person - it is just a string of bytes. To get authentication that person that you have identified (via username or hash) has to provide credentials. Those credentials could be a password, PIN number, IRIS scan, finger print...

Answer (score 0):

I would do the session table to store all the sessions. Store the user's ID and the session ID in a cookie, that way when the user comes back, you can check to see if they are both in the table. If they are, they don't have to log back in.

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is to store the session ids from the different devices and tie them to one user. On the database level that means you don't have a "session_id" field in your user table but a separate table with "session_id" and "user_id" columns.

Please think about the security implications of session fixation and session hijacking. For a description of a more secure "remember me" system, read these articles:

http://fishbowl.pastiche.org/2004/01/19/persistent_login_cookie_best_practice/

http://jaspan.com/improved_persistent_login_cookie_best_practice

Answer (score 0):

> ofcourse I need a secure solution, preventing copying the cookie to another device or changing cookie information (from your user to admin) is important.

Ultimately, this is solving the wrong problem.

The way to prevent this is to:

1. Use HTTPS everywhere.
2. Send all cookies over HTTPS, with the secure and httpOnly flags.

That's it. This is related to the problem of [client authenticity](https://paragonie.com/blog/2016/03/client-authenticity-is-not-server-s-problem). There are some techniques that can stop *lazy attackers* (e.g. user agent), but any of these techniques can be spoofed trivially.